# Reading from specific configuration file

Tags: c#, app-config

I have an application that contain one exe file and several dlls. In one of the classes in my dll file I use `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` to read settings that declare in the main exe file. but when I change the values of sections manually in the file it always return the initial value that I set at the first time.

please tell me what I must do for reading settings from a specific config file in my application.

here's my applicationSettings:

```
<applicationSettings>
  <UltraData.Bonus.BonusControler.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="ProviderName" serializeAs="String">
      <value>WebProvider</value>
    </setting>
  </UltraData.Bonus.BonusControler.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

and I want to read `ProviderName` value.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228063.aspx this should help.

Comment: @kenny - It's for web application, I'm looking for windows application configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out where is my mistake. I must use `<appSettings>` instead of `<applicationSettings>` and read those settings by using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProviderName"]`

Answer (score 0):

The `app.config` file is the only one that is read. There are no `.config` files for DLLs.

You *do* need to restart the application in order for the config to be re-read.

Comment: I use this method **ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).AppSettings.Settings.Count** but it always return 0, It's seems not read from app.config

Comment: @Amir - And what does your config file look like?

Comment: @Amir - Please edit your question and add the information to it. Comments are not a good place for code/xml.